# JavaFX Printable to Image very pix-elated, but perfect to printer

Tags: java, printing, javafx

I have a printable object that prints perfectly fine to a printer, but when i print it to an Image, then it is very pixelated?

Here is my code to setup a printer for printing and to an image

```
private PageFormat setupPrinter() {
    // sizing (standard is 72dpi, so multiple inches by this)
    Double height = 4d * 72d;
    Double width = 3d * 72d;
    Double margin = 0.1d * 72d;

    // now lets print it
    AttributeSet attributes = new HashAttributeSet();
    attributes.add(new Copies(1));

    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();

    // if there are more than 10 items, up the paper size to 6inch. 
    // This will handle up to 24 different items
    if (1 == 2) height = 6d * 72d;

    // set page size
    Paper paper = pageFormat.getPaper();

    paper.setSize(width, height);
    paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, width - (margin * 2), height - (margin * 2));

    // set orientation and paper
    pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

    return pageFormat;
}

private void printToImage() {

    MyPrintable myPrintable = new MyPrintable();

    // setup our printer
    PageFormat pageFormat = setupPrinter();

    // set size of imageView, using the hieght and width values
    double imageHeight = pageFormat.getHeight();
    double imageWidth = pageFormat.getWidth();

    // create our image/graphics
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)imageWidth, (int)imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();

    // color background white
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    ((Graphics2D) graphics).fill(new Rectangle.Float(0, 0, (float)imageWidth, (float)imageHeight));

    // directly call our print method, passing graphics, pageFormat and pageIndex
    try {
        myPrintable.print(graphics, pageFormat, 0);
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    graphics.dispose();

    // set our image
    imgReport.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null));

    // now lets show the preview pane
    reportPane.setVisible(true);
}

public void printToPrinter(ActionEvent event) {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pageFormat = setupPrinter();

    printJob.setPrintable(new MyPrintable(), pageFormat);

    try {
        printJob.print();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }

}

public MyPrintable() {
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        // user (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must translate
        // by the X and Y values in the pageFormat to avoid clipping
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

        // add text etc here
        ........
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how pixelated it is.  Bit it fits in the image perfectly....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a controlling rendering quality
read this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html

example for your code:

```
Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
         RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
graphics.fill(new Rectangle.Float(0, 0, (float)imageWidth, (float)imageHeight));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, rendering quality doesn't help much for JavaFX, at least not yet.  More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797351/