# How to disable anti-aliasing in JavaFX fonts?

Tags: java, css, swing, fonts, antialiasing

Using JavaFX to render HTML content using a `javafx.scene.web.WebView`, the content is always drawn with text anti-aliasing on.

Although this makes fonts look smoother, it often makes the printing of content to a monochrome/thermal style printer (receipt, shipping label) problematic.  A `nearest-neighbor` scale would be much better.

[image: default lcd rendering]

The `awt` and `swing` techniques (`-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings` and `-Dswing.aatext` respectively) don't seem to help JavaFX.

There's an option to switch from `lcd` anti-aliasing to `gray` via `-Dprism.lcdtext=false`, which helps, but doesn't fix the anti-aliasing problem.

[image]

How does one achieve nearest-neighbor font scaling with JavaFX's WebView?

Related: [JavaFX Printable to Image very pix-elated, but perfect to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734001/javafx-printable-to-image-very-pix-elated-but-perfect-to-printer)

Comment: You haven’t said how you’re printing, but it might be worth obtaining the Document using [WebView.getEngine().getDocument()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getDocument--), writing it to a UTF-8 file using an identity Transformer, then passing that file as a URL to the SimpleDoc constructor, along with [DocFlavor.URL.TEXT_HTML_UTF_8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.URL.html#TEXT_HTML_UTF_8).

Comment: I'm rasterizing the content to a `BufferedImage` using `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(<WritableImage ...>, null)`.

Comment: I would avoid the use of images entirely, and instead pass the WebView directly to one of the `printPage` methods of [javax.print.PrinterJob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html).

Comment: @VGR, thanks.  We'll try that, although word of caution to others, the `javafx.print.PrinterJob` mentioned is `Since JavaFX 8.0` only.  Furthermore, there are several printing subsystem bugs on Mac that have been open for years.  In testing, one of these bugs impacts `NEAREST_NEIGHBOR` interpolation during print subsystem scaling. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8017247